# Convert day numbers into dates in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

How do you convert day numbers (1,2,3...728,729,730) to dates in python? I can assign an arbitrary year to start the date count as the year doesn't matter to me.

I am working on learning time series analysis, ARIMA, SARIMA, etc using python. I have a CSV dataset with two columns, 'Day' and 'Revenue'. The Day column contains numbers 1-731, Revenue contains numbers 0-18.154... I have had success building the model, running statistical tests, building visualizations, etc. But when it comes to forecasting using prophet I am hitting a wall.

Here are what I feel are the relevant parts of the code related to the question:

```
# Loading the CSV with pandas. This code converts the "Day" column into the index.
df = read_csv("telco_time_series.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 731 entries, 1 to 731
Data columns (total 1 columns):
#   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
0   Revenue  731 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 11.4 KB
df.head()
Revenue
Day 
1   0.000000
2   0.000793
3   0.825542
4   0.320332
5   1.082554

# Instantiate the model
model = ARIMA(df, order=(4,1,0))

# Fit the model
results = model.fit()

# Print summary
print(results.summary())

# line plot of residuals
residuals = (results.resid)
residuals.plot()
plt.show()

# density plot of residuals
residuals.plot(kind='kde')
plt.show()

# summary stats of residuals
print(residuals.describe())

SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                Revenue   No. Observations:                  731
Model:                 ARIMA(4, 1, 0)   Log Likelihood                -489.105
Date:                Tue, 03 Aug 2021   AIC                            988.210
Time:                        07:29:55   BIC                           1011.175
Sample:                             0   HQIC                           997.070
                            - 731                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ar.L1         -0.4642      0.037    -12.460      0.000      -0.537      -0.391
ar.L2          0.0295      0.040      0.746      0.456      -0.048       0.107
ar.L3          0.0618      0.041      1.509      0.131      -0.018       0.142
ar.L4          0.0366      0.039      0.946      0.344      -0.039       0.112
sigma2         0.2235      0.013     17.629      0.000       0.199       0.248
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.01   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 2.52
Prob(Q):                              0.90   Prob(JB):                         0.28
Heteroskedasticity (H):               1.01   Skew:                            -0.05
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.91   Kurtosis:                         2.73
===================================================================================

df.columns=['ds','y']
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements

m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)

ValueError: Dataframe must have columns "ds" and "y" with the dates and values 
respectively.
```

I've had success with the forecast using prophet if I fill the values in the CSV with dates, but I would like to convert the Day numbers within the code using pandas.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can assign an arbitrary year to start the date count as the year doesn't matter to me(...)Any ideas?*

You might harness `datetime.timedelta` for this task. Select any date you wish as day 0 and then add `datetime.timedelta(days=x)` where x is your day number, for example:

```
import datetime
day0 = datetime.date(2000,1,1)
day120 = day0 + datetime.timedelta(days=120)
print(day120)
```

output

```
2000-04-30
```

encase in function and `.apply` if you have `pandas.DataFrame` like so

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
def convert_to_date(x):
    return datetime.date(2000,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(days=x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'day_n':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df['day_date'] = df['day_n'].apply(convert_to_date)
print(df)
```

output

```
   day_n    day_date
0      1  2000-01-02
1      2  2000-01-03
2      3  2000-01-04
3      4  2000-01-05
4      5  2000-01-06
```